# Specifying type of parameter in F# function declaration

Tags: f#

I am just starting out with F# so this is a bit of basic question on best practise with type inference.

I am trying to write a function that works on a TimeSpan. This is a simplified version of what I am trying to do:

```
let intervalsFromTimespan t = t.TotalMinutes / 5.0
```

Clearly this won't work because I need to somehow state that t is a timespan.

Would the correct way be:

```
let intervalsFromTimespan' t = (t : TimeSpan).TotalMinutes / 5.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
let intervalsFromTimespan (t : TimeSpan) = t.TotalMinutes / 5.0
```

Comment: Thanks - Can't believe I missed that!