# F# - Specify Type in Declaration

Tags: f#

I am new to F#, so forgive me if this question seems silly, or if it is duplicated. If it is a duplicate, I couldn't find the answer.

The closest articles I could find are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11086368/declaring-a-variable-without-assigning) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20128088/specifying-type-of-parameter-in-f-function-declaration). The second link has a hint to an answer, but isn't exact.

My question is this: How would I declare a variable to be specifically one type?

For example, the statement `let i = 1` is basically just saying `i` is an integer, but only because it is set to one. So you could also say `let i = "cake"` and `i` would be a string.

Can you say something like `let int i = 1`? I noticed in the second link that you can kind of "re-declare" a variable by doing something like `<variable> : <type>`, but how would you do this in the initial declaration in F#?

Comment: `let i: int = 1` but in this context, it's kinda pointless to do so.

Comment: Ah, so you basically cast it right after declaration. Thank you! Was driving me crazy. I have to ask, why is it pointless to do so?

Comment: When binding to a variable, you must provide a value. If the value is an int, there's no real need to explicitly declare it. A type annotation would be useful in functions where the parameters need specific types or you need to give hints to the compiler at what they should look like.

Comment: Okay. That makes sense. I was wondering if you did something like `let i : float = 1`, then later used `i` to add to something like 2.53, but it actually throws a syntax error and you would need to put `let i : float = 1.00` instead. Thank you for the info!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To close this question officially, via Jeff Mercado's comment:

`let i: int = 1`

So `let <variable name>:<variable type> = <value>`

If you do something like `let i : float = 1` it will instead throw a syntax error and require you to put in something like `let i : float = 1.00`.